# MySQL insert & Update query gives error while inserting large data

Tags: php, mysql

table structure:

**id int(11)**

**bcontent longtext**

when i run insert query through php if the data which is going to store in bcontent is small (2-3 lines paragraph) then that query runs successfully but when the size of that data is increases (10-11 lines paragraph) that query gives an error. is there problem with **longtext** data type? i also tried **longblob** but no change.

php code:

```
include("conn.php");
$bcontent = $_POST['bcontent'];
$query = mysql_query("insert into blocks (bcontent) values ('$bcontent')");
if($query)
{
//Success message 
}
else
{
//Error message
}
```

when the size of **bcontent** is large php throws //Error message.

i also increase the size of post_max_size to 200M in php.ini but no change.

Error:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use**

actually it gives me an output which i coded in else condition

is there any error is my query or in table structure?
please help me.

Comment: Does your larger content contain single quotes (`'`), by any chance?

Comment: probably you have some data with single quotes and thats breaking the query ? try a single query as `$bcontent = " hello worl'd " ;` and insert it you will come to know

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ya it have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content probably contains quote characters, which you need to escape.

```
$bcontent = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bcontent']);
```

Comment: and people should upgrade to pdo or mysqli

Comment: yes, they should. I've decide to just answer these questions, not tilt at windmills.